# What if a question is looking for a software doing X on Mac OS, and I want a software doing X on Windows?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

There is a question is looking for a software doing X on Mac OS. I am looking for a software doing X on Windows. Shall I create a new question with the same content but just changing the name of the required OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say **Yes**.

With a few suggestions;
include your use case, a bit of background any extra features etc.? (because it would have to be a fairly rare case you couldn't add at least one thing you'd like to see as well as a different OS)

Comment: It might also be a good idea to include a link to the other question, pointing out they are no duplicates. Additionally, that would link them for people finding B first while looking for A :)